# Why does XPath method works but ByClassName method not?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

First of all, I wish you all healthy days. Whenever I try to extract data with byclassname I fail. Can you help me with this? If possible, I would be very happy if you could suggest a resource to learn about them.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Mydoc As New Selenium.WebDriver
Dim TX, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 As String
Mydoc.Start "chrome"
On Error Resume Next
Mydoc.Get "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stack"



x1 =         Mydoc.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div    /div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/span").Text
''only xpath working
Dim classCount As Long
classCount = Mydoc.findElementsByClassName("eg deg").Count
x2 = Mydoc.findElementsByClassName("eg deg").Item(classCount).Text
x3 = Mydoc.FindElementByClassName("eg deg").Text
x4 = Mydoc.findElementsByClassName("eg deg").Item(0).Text
''
x4 = Mydoc.FindElementByCss("eg.deg").Item(classCount).Text
x5 = Mydoc.FindElementByCss("eg.deg")


Range("A" & 1) = x1
Range("A" & 2) = x2
Range("A" & 3) = x3
Range("A" & 4) = x4
Range("A" & 5) = x5
Range("A" & 6) = classCount


End Sub
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcEJl.png)

Comment: If you comment out `On Error Resume Next` where and how does it fail?  `Item()` takes a zero-based index, so you can't pass in the total number of elements to get the last one: you'd need to use `Item(classCount-1)`

Comment: ı tried without  `On Error Resume Next`. It still didn't work. '.Item(0) ' '.Item(1) ''.Item(2) ' '.Item(3) ' ı change by hand by still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used multiple classes in the arguments. Only one class name is accepted.

> **FindElementsByClassName**   :  Finds a list of elements that match the **class name** supplied

Following should work

```
x2 = Mydoc.FindElementByCssSelector(".eg.deg").Item(classCount).Text
```

Comment: you say; if my classname "baran" this method working but when my class name" ba ran" this method idoesn't working? also   `x2 = Mydoc.FindElementByCssSelector(".eg.deg").Text` this working but `x2 = Mydoc.FindElementByCssSelector(".eg.deg").Item(classCount).Text` this not working. the code you provided works. but ".eg.deg" is used in 3 different places on the page. this code only shows the 1st row as a result. How can I view the 2nd and 3rd row?

Comment: When the class name  value is " ba ran", it has two classes (class names). CSS selector .eg.deg has multiple candidate elements. When you use Mydoc.FindElementByCssSelector(".eg.deg") first element is chosen by Selenium. Use Mydoc.FindElemenstByCssSelector(".eg.deg") to get list of candidate element and call the elements by index to get the next elements.

Comment: Thank you so much. I could not fully understand you because my mother tongue was not English. now everything is ok. I need to fix something. Excel Vba is using "FindElementByCss or FindElementsByCss", I couldn't run it with "FindElementByCssSelector or FindElementsByCssSelector".

When I changed the codes to "Mydoc.FindElementsByCss (" "). Item (2) .Text" I got results.

Comment: You will have to master CSS, XPath and other available support classes for locating elements as you continue to use Selenium. For CSS http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2020/02/09/mastering-css-for-selenium-test-automation-2/  For XPath http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2020/01/28/mastering-xpath-for-selenium-test-automation-engineers/.

Comment: thank you again :). I will begin to examine. I wish you healthy days.

Comment: Welcome. Happy test automation